# Spark-mongo connector SparkR read from two collections

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, sparkr

In Spark.mongo connector has serveral lenguages to query in mongo, java and scala provides more info about query diferent collections as follow:

```
./bin/spark-shell --conf "spark.mongodb.input.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.coll
```

And then in code you can specify another collection setting the configuration:

```
sc.loadFromMongoDB(ReadConfig(Map("uri" -> "mongodb://example.com/database.collection")))
```

But I can´t do it with SparkR, SparkR-documentation indicates that you can add in the shell:

```
 ./bin/sparkR --conf "spark.mongodb.input.uri=mongodb://cm/database.collection1"
```

But I don´t know how specify by code another collection to do queries from two diferent collections.

¿How can I specify another mongo collection in SparkR?

Comment: Have you read about the API document about spark context in R language? basicly --conf is equal to adding config into sc.config . I don't know much about sparkR, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set any [configuration options](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/configuration/#input-configuration) when creating a dataframe eg:

```
# Read using the spark config
df <- read.df(sqlContext, source = "com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")

# Read using the passed in uri config
df1 <- read.df(sqlContext, source = "com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource", uri = "mongodb://example.com/database.collection1")
```

In fact you don't need to use the Spark Config at all - it's optional but if you don't you must provide at minimum the `uri`, `database` and `collection` information.